# Google Calendar API: GDataEntryCalendarEvent question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gdata-api, gdata

I'm trying to use the google GData api [to insert an event in a google calendar](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction#Creating_GDataObjects_from_scratch).  My question is this: I don't see anywhere in the header files for [GDataEntryCalendarEvent](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Clients/Calendar/GDataEntryCalendarEvent.h) the ability to add guests to an event?

Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in [GDataEntryEvent](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Clients/Calendar/GDataEntryEvent.h) there are some methods to add participants.

Comment: That be it!  Thanks!  I had just found the GDataWho modules when I came to back to edit my response, but hadn't seen the participants method yet!  Thanks so much!